# Trying to install selectorlib package in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to install a selectorlib package using:

Importing:

`import selectorlib`

Installing in terminal:

`pip install selectorlib`

And i get this error:

...

```
Building wheel for lxml (setup.py)

error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
[115 lines of output]

...

 error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, cssselect, Click, parsel, selectorlib
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

...

```
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

...

Y tried different methods in order to install it:

- Using different interpreters (Python 3.9.6; Python 3.10.9; Python 3.11.1)
- Tried to install in VS Code and PyCharm CE
- Tried to install different selectorlib versions. (Last 3)

Comment: Assuming you are working on a unix platform, lxml requires some C dependencies before it can be installed with pip. Have you checked the [installation instructions](https://lxml.de/installation.html)? According to these instructions, you have to install the dependencies via `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev`

Comment: @psalt I tried to do it and in the end it was exactly as you're saying to me. I needed to install the dependencies. I appreciate a lot your help! Best wishes

Comment: Glad I could help. I added the my comment as an answer in case others face a similar problem. If you like you can choose that answer as "asccepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working on a unix platform, lxml requires some C dependencies before it can be installed with pip.

You can check the official [installation instructions](https://lxml.de/installation.html).

> Unless you are using a static binary distribution (e.g. from a Windows
> binary installer), lxml requires libxml2 and libxslt to be installed,
> in particular:
>
> ```
> libxml2 version 2.9.2 or later.
> libxslt version 1.1.27 or later.
>     We recommend libxslt 1.1.28 or later.
> ```

According to these instructions, you have to install the dependencies via

`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev`